# Basic procedure in passing ORM object to tempate

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm experimenting with https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base and trying to pass a sqlalchemy orm object to a jinja2 template.

My property model is;

```
class Property(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'properties'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))
    body = db.Column(db.String(1400))
    img = db.Column(db.String(140))
    ....
```

In my main/views.py I have:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import db
from app.models import Property

from . import main


@main.route('/')
def index():
    props = db.session.query(Property).all()
    return render_template('main/index.html')
```

I understand that to pass a variable to a template you would do :

```
    return render_template('main/index.html', pr= props)
```

However trying:

```
>>> type(props[0])
 <class 'app.models.property.Property'>
```

This seems like the wrong type of object to pass. I would assume you would pass somthing more generic like a list of dicts. What is the best approach in passing a list of sqlalchemy objects into a jinja2 template?

Comment: " I would assume you would pass somthing more generic like a list of dicts." Why do you assume that? You can pass whatever you want.

Comment: what makes you think it's the wrong type ?

Comment: I may have mispoken but it seemed to me more likely that people passed in commonly used more generic data structures (lists,dicts etc). Is there a best practice for what gets passed in to jinja2 templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja2 can handle any sort of Python object being passed to the template renderer, because it is written in Python and specifically is meant to work like that. So if you pass that `props` list to `render_template`, it will work just fine.

You can access object methods and attributes like normal, and even do iteration:

```
{% for prop in pr %}
  <p>Title: {{ prop.title }}</p>
  <p>Body: {{ prop.body }}</p>
  <img src="{{ prop.image }}" />
{% endfor %}
```